# How can I handle width in flexbox with flexDirection column?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox

I thinks I have a problem to apply css flexbox to a button.

Let me give you an exemple :

```
<div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
  <input />
  <input />
  <input />
  <button>click here</button>
</div>
```

How can i handle the width (without width, only using flex) of my input/button becuz if I use flex its on the height because of flex direction. I must miss something but i can't see what !

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `align-items` css attribute to align items with its' own width.

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start;">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <button>click here</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to try